# SQL CE Replication

Tags: sql, windows, mobile, windows-ce, replication

I am developing a mobile app that needs to synchronize with a database server.

I intend to have a menu in my app that says "Synchronize". So when the device is docked and connect to the computer. The user can open the app, click the "Synchronize" button and have the database merged with the server.

Please i need hints, i will these work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753)

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753):

> Microsoft Sync Framework is a
>   comprehensive synchronization platform
>   that enables collaboration and offline
>   access for applications, services, and
>   devices. It features technologies and
>   tools that enable roaming, sharing,
>   and taking data offline. By using Sync
>   Framework, developers can build sync
>   ecosystems that integrate any
>   application with any data from any
>   store that uses any protocol over any
>   network.

- [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281959.aspx)
- [Sync Services for SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 in Visual Studio 2008](http://keithelder.net/2007/09/23/sync-services-for-sql-server-compact-edition-3-5-in-visual/)
- [Sync Framework Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/)